# Redirect www to https non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my site from www to https non www. I have this code in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ /page.php?title=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Can you suggest changes in the .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Match your URL with www. and rewrite to it SSL https without www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Match your URL that does not have SSL https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```