# Rewrite url with www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

I am trying to rewrite my site pages url and redirecting www to without https url. Buts its not working for me. I tried

Note: my page url also contains number and alphabets

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z].+)$ /page.php?title=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://travelinsure.ca
```

Comment: Its giving "Server not found" when I try to open site with www

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect www to https non www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214171/redirect-www-to-https-non-www)